# Call a function on bootstrap modal close(Both through escape button and any other way) in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angular, bootstrap-modal

I am working with angular. I have **Bootstrap** modal popup. I have called a function when its gets closed. But the problem is there are other ways to close like pressing escape button or simply clicking on the screen. I don't know how to call the same function when these events like escape occur? I have googled stackoverflow and couldn't find a proper solution.

**[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-modal-input-value-ggz9xq?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)**

Comment: Check these options - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#events

Comment: I did see that but I dont know how to apply that on angular code?Can you please update with code in that stackblitz @Abhijit

Comment: I have edited your code - 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/bootstrap-modal-input-value-cg195j?file=app/app.component.ts

Comment: Its not working. kindly check ur code @Abhijit

Comment: It will work, just try changing some code,  it's a issue with stackblitz

Comment: ERROR
Error: $ is not defined @Abhijit

Comment: Did you tried changing any code in stackblitz  ?

Comment: yes but still didnt work sir @Abhijit

Comment: I updated the code in stackblitz, check again

Answer (score 1):

You can add an even listener on `hide.bs.modal` event.
This even fires immediately when the hide instance method has been called. You can see more detail in the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/)

Comment: I am doing it in angular. I cant understand what you are saying. Can you please update with code in that stackblitz? @Milad Esrafiliyan

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `blur` event of your modal element. And `onBlur` do whatever you want to.

Comment: I am doing it in angular. . Can you please update with code in that stackblitz? @Rohit Khandelwal

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem using [Angular Bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples). I created the initial code for my modal by referencing the [Modal with options](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#options) documentation.

The [NgbModalOptions](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/api#NgbModalOptions) has a `beforeDismiss` option that you can use to pass a callback function that will run before the modal closes. I used it like this to clear data before the modal is closed:

```
// my-component.component.html

<ng-template #modalTemplate let-modal>
  ...
</ng-template>

<button
  type="button"
  (click)="openModal(modalTemplate)"
>
  Open Modal
</button>
```

```
// my-component.component.ts

openDialog(modalTemplate) {
  this.modalService.open(modalTemplate, { size: 'lg', beforeDismiss: () => {
      this.clearModalData();
      return true;
    },
  });
}
```

I hope that helps! I use Angular at work, but if you are looking for a simple JavaScript framework that gets out of your way and lets you be productive, then may I suggest [Svelte.js](https://svelte.dev/) (specifically the [SvelteKit](https://kit.svelte.dev/) framework). It is awesome! Good luck!